# Laravel whereIn in array

Tags: php, laravel

I have array of collections. In collections I have relation. How I can use `whereIn` in these relations?

```
$arrayCollections = $category->products;

$arrayCollections = $arrayCollections->character->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4]); //I need use whereIn in character relation. I get error: Property [character] does not exist on this collection instance.

foreach($arrayCollections as $product) {
    .... //but in foreach I can use $product->character
}
```

Relation in product model::

```
public function character()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductCharacter');
}
```

Comment: What is in `$arrayCollections`?

Comment: show your database table and where character is defined

Comment: `character` - relation of model products

Comment: Have you tried to `dd($arrayCollections)` to see if `character` is in the collection?

Comment: @kerbholz no, In `arrayCollections` I get array. And yes, I have `character` in collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$characters = $category->products()->character()->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4])->get();

foreach($characters as $character) {
    // $character
}
```

Comment: `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::character does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need an indirect relationship. The best way to get this is by using [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

In your `Category` model

```
public function characters() {
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Character::class, Product::class); // Has many characters through products
}
```

Then you can directly do:

```
 $characters = $category->characters()->whereIn('id', [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])->get();
```

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`

Answer (score 0):

what about this ? I added first() :

```
$characters = $category->products()->first()->character()->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4])->get();

foreach($characters as $character) {
    // $character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$arrayCollections = $category->products()->with('character')->whereIn('id' ,  [1,2,3,4])->get();

foreach($arrayCollections as $product) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the whereHas() methode and with() method.

```
$arrayCollections = $category->products()
    ->whereHas('character', function($character){
        $character->whereIn('id' ,  [1,2,3,4]);
    })
    ->with('character')->get();
```

This will get you a collection of "products" that have "characters" attach to it that have ID in [1,2,3,4].